# Can I use an HTML5 audio element to play a sound file in a functional component using React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, react-hooks

I built a timer using functional components and React Hooks. When the timer reaches 00:00, an audio clip plays. My current code works using new Audio(). Here's a sample:

```
const Timer = () => {
   const [myAudio] = useState(new Audio(soundfile));

   const handleBeep = () => {
      myAudio.play();
   }
```

It works but doesn't pass the FCC test because I'm supposed to use an HTML5  tag. I tried the useRef() hook to select the audio file instead. However, myAudio was not recognized as an Audio object:

```
   const myAudio = useRef();

   const handleBeep = () => {
      myAudio.play();
   }

return (
   <div>
   <audio id='beep' ref={myAudio} src={soundfile} type='audio'/>
   </div>
```

I've used ref for  tags in class components before and I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with React Hooks in functional components. I would hate to have to totally restructure my code just to pass the test, so any input would be helpful.

Comment: The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) state: 
*"`useRef` is like a “box” that can hold a mutable value in its **`.current`** property"*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `React.useRef` returns an object with the following interface:

```
interface ReactRef<T> {
  current: null | T
}
```

where `T` is the type of the value for which you expect to capture a reference. This is mentioned in the docs [here](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/eb0ae240c3e99e6bdd658fc490dd767699b124d1/content/docs/hooks-reference.md#useref-useref).

So the reason `myAudio.play()` isn't working is that you need to access the ref with `myAudio.current.play()`.

It's also advisable to make sure you handle the `null` case doing something like

```js
if (myAudio.current !== null) {
  myAudio.current.play()
}
```